# Is it recommended to change RDS instance type regularly to scale down at night?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I got an app that is heavily used during the daytime and almost not used at night and on sundays.
RDS MySQL costs are quite high and I am wondering if I can not just downscale at night and upscale in the morning by changing instance type from m5.4xlarge to m5.large and back.
I dont want to fully turn it of since we got some crons running at night and also some users might want to access the system out of business hours but usually the DB just runs around 2% CPU around those hours.
The only recommendations I found about this kind of usage is to turn off instances which I would like to avoid. I manually changed instance type in the last days and to me it seems it should be no problem to automate this. The downtime of aprox. 2min for the instance change is completely acceptable for me and I could schedule this for times where usage is already low.
This question is not about how this is technically possible but if it is generally recommended or if there is any downside I didnt think if yet.
I am really wondering why I didnt find anything about this since it seems quite a common usecase for any business app that is used only in one timezone.

I did that manually and seems to work fine. I searched the internet for hours about this but didnt find anything useful pro or contra.

Comment: I think the only con is downtime but as you said, it's not an issue for you. You can set up a cron which does this at night when there is no/less activity.

Answer (score 0):

It's not something that people typically do. Amazon Aurora Serverless would be a much better way to handle this.

Aurora Serverless v2 is an on-demand, autoscaling configuration for Amazon Aurora. Aurora Serverless v2 helps to automate the processes of monitoring the workload and adjusting the capacity for your databases. Capacity is adjusted automatically based on application demand. You're charged only for the resources that your DB clusters consume. Thus, Aurora Serverless v2 can help you to stay within budget and avoid paying for computer resources that you don't use.

With the added benefit that Aurora can deliver up to five times the throughput of MySQL.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless-v2.html#aurora-serverless-v2.advantages

Comment: Thanks. I am already looking into this option as well, but currently I got MySQL reservations until mid 2023